# IPad Orientation check wrongly

Tags: iphone

i am check device and interface orientation programetically but every time it goes to landscape Orientation even in portraite mode also
Here is my code please give me Solution:-

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft||[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]== UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight || [self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
     {

     }
     else
     {


     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use

```
      if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    { 
    //orientation is portrait
    } 

    if(  [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
    //orientation is landscape
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

 if ( ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] ==  UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)  )
 {
    //Portrait coding
 }
 else if(([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) ||           [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft))
{
 //Landscape coding
 }
```